# How to update Ruby On Rails app code aws ec2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, deployment, aws-ec2-instance-connect

Any AWS experts there?

I was wondering let say if we have rails app deployed on aws ec2 on 2 instances.
Now if I connect to app over the ssh and update code (ruby code on rails app, just minor changes in a code)

- 1 -Do I need anything else there?
- 2 -Do I need to do that on every app instance?
- 3 -Do I need to do any reboot of instance?

Changes is so small it is not worth to redeploy app again which takes in our case 90 minutes.

Comment: Yes, changes have to be made on every app instance.  You will likely need to restart the rails app on each instance.

Comment: Thank you man @dbugger i will try that.